# Order of `float` and `caption` packages in preamble

Tags: tables, floats, listings, captions, algorithms

I am using `float` and `caption` packages in my document, and also packages like `tabularx`, `listings`, `algorithm`... that (as far as I know) define floating *elements* or elements that  have captions associated to them.

In the particular case of `listings` package, I think it also calls or loads `float`, if I am not wrong.

So, my question is this: Where in the preamble is it better or more appropriate to load `float` and `caption` packages —*before* or *after* loading other packages that create floating environments?

Sorry if my question doesn't make sense, maybe I didn't get the whole idea...

Anyway, really looking forward to your answers,

Comment: The documentation of `caption` says you are free to call it where you want. `float`says nothing.

Comment: It usually doesn't matter or make any difference except for highly invasive packages like hyperref that need to redefine everything so like to come last. Unless you have a particular problem just don't worry about it and load in whatever order you want. (LaTeX won't load the same package twice). If you do find a case where the order makes a difference you can ask again about that specific clash.

Comment: OK, thank you. In case I find concrete issues or unexpected interactions, I'll search for answers again. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no preference on the order in which to load them.